# Rspec Target Font Awesome Icon Link

Tags: rspec, font-awesome

Is there a way to have rspec click a specific font awesome icon? I'm very new to rspec so I apologize if this is a very basic question.

I tried `click_link '.fa-envelope'` but it seems like that is looking for the name of the link.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here's the html of the link I'm trying to click:

```
  <div class="col-sm-4 align-center">
    <a class="email-link" href="/contact"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use capybara so you can use finders instead:

```
find(".email-link").find(".fa-envelope").click
```

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders

Comment: Just about - seems I needed to do find(".email-link").click to actually go to the link, but that definitely works!

Answer (score 13):

You also can use title attribute :

```
<div class="col-sm-4 align-center">
  <a class="email-link" href="/contact" title="Send email"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
</div>
```

Then in your feature spec you can write :

```
click_link 'Send email'
```

Hope this helped !

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is an old question, but I stumbled upon this problem and none of the solutions provided in this thread and other SO threads worked for me.

It's a known bug in Capybara 2.1 as mentioned in [this thread](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/494). Here's a direct link to the suggested [solution](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/494#issuecomment-18291161).

HTML snippet & solution for OP's problem.

HTML Snippet:

```
  <div class="col-sm-4 align-center">
    <a class="email-link" href="/contact"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
  </div>
```

Solution:

```
Capybara.page.execute_script %($('i.fa-envelope"').click())
```

*PS: CSS finders won't work, so we'll have to use `execute_script` method for now until the bug gets fixed.*